# Pass hidden, loaded array as parameter to http.get OnSubmit, Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have an api that returns two arrays verified in postman and using developer tools response

c#

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUsersAcccountContract(string username)
    {
        var users = await (
            from u in db.users
            select new { u.account_number,
                         u.contract_number }).ToListAsync();

        return Json(users);
    }
```

I call this in angular ngOnInit

```
this.sub = this.aroute.params.subscribe(params => {
  if(currentUser.username != null) {
    let apiURL = this.systemSettings.getWebAPISettings('contractNumber');
    let token = this.userService.getToken();
    // Setup the header with the auth token
    let headers = new Headers({ 
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    });
    let urlOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, params: {
      username: currentUser.username
    }});
    this.http.get(apiURL, urlOptions).subscribe(res => {
      this.contractnumbers = res.json();
    });
  }
});
```

model default:

```
contractnumbers:ContractNumbers = {
account_number:     null,
contract_number:    null
```

}

The problem is that I keep getting null values for my account and contract numbers when I go to use them OnSubmit

this.contractnumbers.account_number is always null

Why?

Comment: If you're using Angular 6, you should be using HttpClient (not Http), and therefore there is  no need to do `res.json()`. The value of `res` should automatically be the JSON.parsed response

Comment: used constructor to get what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Please check where is `contractnumbers` initialized. looks like it doesn't have any value where you are trying to access it. Is it declared and initialized in the component class?

You should be able to send query params using [HttpParam](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams).

```
    const params = new HttpParams()
            .set('account_number', 'value here')
            .set('contract_number', 'value here');
    return this.httpClient.get(`${apiURL}`, { headers, params })
```

Comment: Thanks, I have the param part no sweat. I put contractnumbers above the constructor. before I call ngOnIt. contractnumbers:ContractNumbersDTO = {
    account_number:     null,
    contract_number:    null
  }